# Writing C++ code inside of c#

Tags: c#, c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you write a block of c++ code inside C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196390/can-you-write-a-block-of-c-code-inside-c)

Is it possible to write `C++` code inside of `C#` purely?

For example:

```
class MyClass
{
    public void MyCSharpFunction(){Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");}
    public void MyCPlusPlusFunction(){std::cout<<"Hello World"<<std::endl;}
}
```

I know that you can do this through DLL's, however, I could not find any information about if it was possible to do this *without* the use of DLL's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8%28VS.71%29.aspx) code, but not directly C++:

```
// cs_unsafe_keyword.cs
// compile with: /unsafe
using System;
class UnsafeTest 
{
   // unsafe method: takes pointer to int:
   unsafe static void SquarePtrParam (int* p) 
   {
      *p *= *p;
   }
   unsafe public static void Main() 
   {
      int i = 5;
      // unsafe method: uses address-of operator (&)
      SquarePtrParam (&i);
      Console.WriteLine (i);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Nope, it certainly is not.  [30 chars]

Comment: does ASM inside C count as an example?

Comment: Or what about JavaScript inside HTML?

Comment: @StanleyZ: ...yes fair enough; there are examples of this, I spoke too quickly.  Of course, the question is about C#, not C, and the answer is still no.  Offending bit removed.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: How many javascript interpreters do you know of that also handle the HTML parsing?